# Google map current location with circle around it

Tags: android

I want to show map in my android app with current location and in that i have to set seek bar for specifying the range of my current area and can set the range on dragging on seek bar.?

Comment: Paste your code,Shows your tried.

Comment: Specify language (is it java or is a phonegapp app), post some of your code, and where do you think it could be wrong.

Comment: check this: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder

Comment: I am using java and making code in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Circle circle;

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;

        circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(37.4, -122.1))
            .radius(1000)
            .strokeWidth(10)
            .strokeColor(Color.GREEN)
            .fillColor(Color.argb(128, 255, 0, 0))
            .clickable(true);

        map.setOnCircleClickListener(new OnCircleClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCircleClick(Circle circle) {
                // Flip the r, g and b components of the circle's
                // stroke color.
                int strokeColor = circle.getStrokeColor() ^ 0x00ffffff;
                circle.setStrokeColor(strokeColor);
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Checkout below links:

[Draw shapes on Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes)

[Documentations of Circle class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle)